# Attributes in html tags and angular is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I´m creating application for students where the user is gonna be able to select text and highlight the text, now what i´m doing is get the selected text saved on the server to have persistent marker, in the document each paragraph is a block and each block has a id, in that way i can know where was the selection made, when i get the marker back from the server i get a list of marker per document, i use the start and end of the selection to know where i need to place the marker in the text, when i place the marker a use  i create a string like this:

```
const markerText = `<mark class="${marker.color}"
    data-marker-id="${marker.id}">${textSelected}</mark>`;
```

and i replaced for the one on the original text, but for some reason when replace the text only the `class` attribute of the mark tag appear in the html, for some reason the `data-marker-id` it doesn´t.

i event try to use `[attr.data-marker.id]="${marker.id}"`

because the paragraph(blocks of text) are coming from the server with html markup i getting the content of the block with html tags as string so i´m using

```
<p [innerHTML]="block.text"></p>
```

any idea why....?

Comment: That's what interpolation is for. Just compile  your `markerText` - `\`<mark class="{{marker.color}}"
    data-marker-id="${marker.id}">{{textSelected}}</mark>\`;`

Comment: then `$compile(markerText)($scope)`

Comment: but that doesn´t  explain why the `data-marker-id` attribute doesn´t appear, is a change the attribute for `title` work.

Answer (score 2):

I think angular teams dropped the $compile functionnality in Angular (2+). It is still possible to load remote html strings and put them in [innerHTML] but that is all. There is no native nor simple way to interpolate data from remote HTML.

See this post : 
https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/forget-compile-in-angular-2-a2893d8291b1